# Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 different running time in ffmpeg?

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I am developing a new codec in FFmpeg (https://github.com/magonzalezc/LHE branch lhe_develop). I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 recently and I have realized that my running time has increased. I have not changed anything but the OS. However, JPEG is still running in the same time.  My guess is that my codec is using big arrays of data with precalculated data and, somehow, RAM access is slower in Ubuntu 16.04. Other reason can be that OpenMP, which is used by my codec, is not working as well as it did with Ubuntu 14.04.

Have you noticed this issue with your programs in Ubuntu 16.04? Any idea of what is exactly happening?

Thank you!

Comment: You should profile your code and understand which part exactly causing this delta. Your OS can have different settings than the previous one. For example the RAM swapping settings.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Who would expect two different versions of an OS or programs to provide exactly the same timing? Also you don't even provide how you measure the "running time", nor do you define what you mean with "running time".

Comment: @Olaf I am asking because I dont have nothing to expect. If I was an expert, i would not be here. Apart from this, "running time" is measured by ffmpeg. After coding an image or video, it gives you a "speed" parameter. This parameter returns the same result when an image is coded with JPEG in both Ubuntu 14 and 16. However, my codec is slower.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Thank you, I will check RAM settings but I have not changed nothing. I am using default settings.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue?